# Some issues with DEingesystem

Tags: differential-equations, eigenvalues

I would like to solve (get its eigenvalues/vectors) the Sturm-Liouville problem, for the following differential operator: $L =\partial_{r} \partial_{r} \psi(r)$. Also, I would like to impose the following boundary conditions:$ B1 = \psi(0)=1, B2= \psi(2)=0.$

I have tried several different things and the only one that seems to work out is the following:

```
L = D[\[Psi][r], r, r]; 

\[Lambda] = 2; 

B1 = \[Psi][0] == 1; 

B2 = \[Psi][2] == 0; 

{ev, ef} = DEigensystem[L, \[Psi][r], {r, 0, 2}, 2]

Plot[{Evaluate[ef], function}, {r, 0, 5}]
```

It is clear that no conditions were settled in this example. I am well aware that within the documentation, it is written on how to use to Dirichilet condition, as example, but not for general boundary/initial conditions.

With this, my questions are the following:

1) Why it only accepts second-order operators?

2) What conditions is it using when I do not specify it (like in my example)?

3) Tweaking around with the part written $\{r,0,2\}$, in the DEigensystem function, it seems in a way, that the conditions are changing, but I cannot see how. What exactly is this term doing?

4) And the most important question for my problem is: how do I set any two arbitrary conditions (like $B1$ and $B2$ given in my example)?

Comment: Why don't you read the tutorial?

Comment: Well, I am sorry, perhaps I am really missing something. I went through the documentation of DEigensystem and could not find what I wanted. Perhaps, if possible, you may link me to this tutorial?

Comment: OK! I will point out two points: 1) Homogeneous `DirichletCondition` or `NeumannValue` boundary conditions may be included. Inhomogeneous boundary conditions will be replaced with corresponding homogeneous boundary conditions. 2) When no boundary condition is specified on the boundary $\partial \Omega $, then this is equivalent to specifying a Neumann 0 condition.

Comment: I think I got it, thank you. So, in my case, I did the following:

{ev, ef} = 
 DEigensystem[{L, DirichletCondition[\[Psi][r] == 0, True]}, \[Psi][
   r], {r, 0, 2}, 3]

Which sets the BCs in both 0 and 2 to == 0, as desired.

One more question, if I may, can I set a boundary condition to infinity? It does not work when I use it.

Comment: It depends on the operator. For example, try `L = -Laplacian[u[x], {x}] + x^2 u[x];
DEigensystem[L, u[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 2]`. Will get `{{1, 3}, {E^(-(x^2/2)), 2 E^(-(x^2/2)) x}}`

Comment: If you want to do higher order equations in 1 dimension then I have a package that may be helpful